# How to make class files into a JAR file

Tags: java, android

I have a JAR file that I wanted to edit a string inside on of it's classes . So I extracted it using Winrar , done the changes I wanted and saved it . Now I have a folder with subfolders inside that contains class files (about 30 one) .My question here is how can I recreate the Jar file from those folders&files ? Like it's it's doing the reverse action of extracting the Jar file .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a .zip file, rename it (with WinRAR) to something.jar so it becomes a .jar archive and then copy the folders in there.

**But what you are doing is not really recommended to be done**
You shouldn't extract and re-archive it like that.

**And DON'T I repeat DON'T edit .class files!**

Comment: Hi I'll do that , but can I know why editing class file is bad?

Comment: when I did that it said the file is corrupted

Comment: You shouldn't edit .class files EVER because you can skrew something up massively if you don't know what you are doing <.<

Comment: I probably is corrupted because the files aren't where they are supposed to be. Or you edited them wrong.

Comment: I've tried the method again and it worked ! thanks very much .

Comment: I also know what I'm doing and it actually works perfectly now =)

Answer (score 1):

Jar file is basically a zip file - however the best way to edit jars is to use a file manager (like Total Commander). You can delete, copy, rename, ... whatever, transparently inside the archive.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29

May be only one tip for the Total Commander - to enter the archive just use **Ctrl-Pagedown**. And I don't think that is something wrong on jar editing (in some circumstances you have no other option). However class files editing... it is a different game ...

Comment: Hi there,Well I've tried it and it works perfectly now , thanks ! I just need to fix my class file editing method and everything will be ok :D